# Uncaught ReferenceError: Add to cart button is not working

Tags: error, addtocart, magento-community, ajax, magento1.9.2.4

When I  click any product from the home page "The New Born" section, **Add to cart** button is not working and I am not able to scroll to the "Product Details" section

The Google chrome console is giving the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm is not defined
>       
> at addCartOnDetail (ajaxcart.js:3)
>       
> at initAjaxcart (ajaxcart.js:3)
>       
> at HTMLDocument. (ajaxcart.js:3)
>       
> at o (jquery.min.js:2)
>       
> at Object.fireWith (jquery.min.js:2)
>       
> at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
>       
> at HTMLDocument.B (jquery.min.js:2)

Reference Link:

1. http://dev.ornativa.in/black-rose-stud

But if I open the same product from [Earrings](http://dev.ornativa.in/earrings) category everything is working properly.

Even if I posting the link in the social media then also the same problem is occurring.

Comment: Reference Link: not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

1> Go to

```
1. System > Configuration > Web 

2. Open the tab "Search Engine Optimization"

3. And then turn it to "Off"
```